# How does Bootstrap namespace its JavaScript components?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a global object that Bootstrap creates when initializing one of its components, e.g. Tabs?  How does it work?

Using Bootstrap 3.2.

Comment: `$.fn.tabs = ...` Is that the answer to your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First they define

```
var Tab = function (element) {
    this.element = $(element)
}
```

Then they go further and prototype `Tab`:

```
Tab.prototype.activate = function (element, container, callback) {
    var $active    = container.find('> .active')
    var transition = callback
    //...
}
```

And finally they add `Tab` as a jQuery method using their `Plugin` factory:

```
function Plugin(option) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this = $(this)
      var data  = $this.data('bs.tab')

      if (!data) $this.data('bs.tab', (data = new Tab(this)))
      if (typeof option == 'string') data[option]()
    })
  }

  $.fn.tab             = Plugin
  $.fn.tab.Constructor = Tab
```

`Plugin` seems to be something like the jQuery UI Plugin Factory, so you call `$("#a").tab("method")` and the `Plugin` object will call the corresponding method on a `Tab` object.

Comment: Ahh... when I was on their page I was able to type "Plugin" into the console and see that it was a function, but the only thing that appeared in Object.keys(Plugin) was a toSTring function.  I should have seen the $.fn.tab and Plugin.call($(this), 'show'); !

Comment: @user1809836 No, you shouldn't. It's the factory pattern. `Plugin` is used to insatiate the object that really handles the calls to the jQuery plugin, it's a bit like a bridge. It's similar to this: http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/